# Find all index that needs to be rebuilt

Tags: oracle, indexing, oracle12c

I have been searching for a way to find all the indices that needs to be re-built. But couldn't find a syntax on the web.

Is there a syntax to find the same?

Comment: Littlefoot gave a good answer from his angle, but I find your question rather vague.  Other than an index that is marked 'unusable', by what criteria would you think an index needs to be rebuilt?  A lot of people buy into the _myth_ that indexes just need to be periodically rebuilt for "performance" reasons. Or something even more vague.  If you really want to learn about oracle indexes, goggle 'Richard Foote'.  He's arguably the leading expert on oracle indexes and their internal workings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is *unusable*. Have a look at the following example:

```
SQL> create table test (id number);

Table created.

SQL> create index i1t on test (id);

Index created.
```

Make the index unusable:

```
SQL> alter index i1t unusable;

Index altered.

SQL> select index_name from user_indexes where status = 'UNUSABLE';

INDEX_NAME
------------------------------
I1T
```

Rebuild it and check its status again:

```
SQL> alter index i1t rebuild;

Index altered.

SQL> select index_name from user_indexes where status = 'UNUSABLE';

no rows selected

SQL>
```

---

Of course, you wouldn't rebuild them manually - write a script to do it for you. For example:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> begin
  2    for cur_r in (select index_name from user_indexes
  3                  where status = 'UNUSABLE'
  4                 )
  5    loop
  6      dbms_output.put_line('Rebuilding index ' || cur_r.index_name);
  7      execute immediate 'alter index ' || cur_r.index_name || ' rebuild';
  8    end loop;
  9  end;
 10  /
Rebuilding index I2T
Rebuilding index I1T

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```